# Skype suddenly stop working after some time, each time. Don't know why

Tags: windows-7, crash, skype

Skype suddenly stop working after some time, each time. Don't know why. Duration is not fixed.

I get this error

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Skype.exe
  Application Version:  5.0.0.156
  Application Timestamp:    4cf901f4
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdaae
  Exception Code:   e0fafafa
  Exception Offset: 00009617
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Do you possibly have two dots in your username?</strike>

I found this on Skype's [support](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCW-2385) site:

> Raul Liive commented on SCW-2385
>   (Skype crashing when username has two
>   dots in row) saying: Yes we have
>   figured out the problem.
>
> Issue appears to people who have more
>   than one dot in row in username.
>
> We are working on fixing it.
>
> Currently workaround is to use old
>   version.

I would recommend upgrading to the latest version from inside Skype, using the Help menu option. I discovered tonight that there is a 5.1.0.104 for Windows.

Comment: no i have single dot

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: I've upgraded the skype. let's see what happens now

Answer (score 2):

1. Close Skype.

   1. Right-click the Skype icon in the system tray (at the bottom right of the screen)
   2. Choose Quit.
2. Ensure that "Show hidden files and folders" is switched on.

   1. Click Start, type run and press Enter.
   2. Type control folders and click OK.
   3. Select the View tab and ensure relevant entry is enabled.
3. Locate the shared.xml file.

   1. Click Start, type run and press Enter.
   2. Type %appdata%\skype and click OK.
   3. Delete the shared.xml file.
4. Restart Skype. The shared.xml file will be recreated